# Populating Custom Settings field using Apex

Tags: apex, custom-field, customsetting, fields

I'm trying to populate/set/put/initialize a custom setting's field with a calculated value within my apex code. The field type is number. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 41):

For **Hierarchy** custom settings, you can get an instance, then populate and insert it:

```
//fetches or creates a Custom Setting at the organization level 
HierarchySetting__c setting = HierarchySetting__c.getOrgDefaults();
setting.CustomField__c = 'http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/';
upsert setting;
```

Note the use of `upsert`

Or with **List** custom settings: new one up with the fields and insert:

```
upsert new ListSetting__c(
    Name = 'sandbox',
    CustomField__c = 'https://test.salesforce.com/'
);

upsert new ListSetting__c(
    Name = 'production',
    CustomField__c = 'https://login.salesforce.com/'
);
```

Check out the docs:

- [Apex Developer Guide: Custom Settings Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm)

Comment: Can you clarify something for me?  In the hierarchical custom settings, why are users without the customize application privilege able to upsert the custom setting, when that privilege seems to be required? https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Apex doesn't enforce CRUD security or FLS unless you're in execute anonymous context. So this code runs alright regardless of the user's privileges. @nivyaj